# Centralizar elemento no tkinter Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Estou fazendo alguns testes com o módulo em Python 3.
Gostaria de saber como posso centralizar um elemento em uma janela do tkinter começando com o seguinte código:

```
import tkinter as tk
window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("200x600")
label1 = tk.Label(text="Hello world!", font="Arial 10 bold")
```

Neste caso, como posso centralizar a Label no label1?

Comment: o que você quer centralizar e aonde? Se você quer centralizar o label `label1` na janela `window`, primeiro você precisa definir o parente do Label: `tk.Label(window, text="Hello world!", font="Arial 10 bold")` e depois posicionar usando grid, pack ou place. O grid e o pack tem parâmetros específicos para centralização. a segunda opção seria centralizar o texto no label. Isso você faz com a opção `anchor` do Label

Comment: Valeu pela sugestão, Flávio, mas já testei todos esses métodos e para mim não funcionou. Já tive outra ideia do que fazer e já vou aplicar esta ideia nos meus projetos.

Comment: O que pode estar acontecedo então é que ou você está em um elemento que não está expandido. Use `label1.pack(fill='both', expand=True)` que irá resolver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achei o que você precisa, e comigo funcionou.
Espero que funcione para ti.

> site: exame TI [https://www.ti-enxame.com/pt/python/como-centrar-uma-janela-na-tela-no-tkinter/969509846/]

Tk fornece uma função auxiliar que pode fazer isso como tk::PlaceWindow, mas eu não acredito que tenha sido exposto como um método empacotado no Tkinter. Você centralizaria um widget usando o seguinte:

```
from tkinter import *

app = Tk()
app.eval('tk::PlaceWindow %s center' % app.winfo_pathname(app.winfo_id()))
app.mainloop()
```

Essa função também deve lidar com vários monitores corretamente. Ele também tem opções para centralizar em outro widget ou em relação ao ponteiro (usado para colocar menus pop-up), para que eles não caiam da tela.

Comment: Muito obrigado, electro03! O código que você colocou na resposta não me ajudou muito, mas o segundo código do link junto a pergunta resolveu meu problema.